# Bash: error with cd and path variables

Tags: bash, variables, github, path, cd

Here is the code in question:

```
path_prefix='opt/copyright_service/gitHub'
while read line
do
    user=$line
    echo $user
    while read line
    do
        repoName=$line

        path="/$path_prefix/$user"

        echo $path

        cd $path
    done < $2
done < $1
```

The output is:

```
username
/opt/copyright_service/gitHub/username
: No such file or directoryopyright_service/gitHub/username
```

Why is it not recognizing the full path in the cd command?  Before I added in the user feature I had it reading a repository name from a file, and it did that without a problem, but now that I have it doing both, it doesn't work.

The content of the file it is reading is "username"

I have tried many ways of concatenating $path, by specifying path prefix as cd is called, by concatenating $path_prefix and $user in the cd command(cd /$path_prefix/$user)

Any ideas?

Comment: Your script is not complete in the question.

Comment: I thought all the needed information was there, but I added the endings of the loop, since the processes in between are insignificant for this question.

Comment: @Bushmills what do you mean?  They read two separate files, and store them in two separate variables.

Comment: Run it as `bash -ex script.sh` and show us what you get.

Comment: instead of echo $path, put there  hd <<< "$path" and show that output,  hd utility comes with bsdmainutils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big guess: Your script is not in UNIX format. Try using `dos2unix` with it, or use an editor that can convert it well. Using `sed -i -e 's|\r||' your_script.sh` may work as well.

If not, it's probably the input files that aren't.

Comment: I tried running the command you provided, using the correct file-name, and had no luck.

Comment: @user1762196 How about the files you process. Are they in check?

Comment: That was the issue, I transfered the text files from my windows machine straight to my server, now it does work though.